# Device is connected to network, but doesn't have an IP

Tags: networking, router, ip

I have a DroboShare (NAS drive) connected to my router (directly, not wifi), but the software that runs the Drobo couldn't find it.
I can access the drive directly by Start --> Run --> "\droboshare", but I can't seem to find it IP. But it doesn't show up when I go into Network and look at the network devices.
I have logged into the modem and cannot find the device on the DHCP table.

Does that mean it doesn't have an IP assigned to it? How would I have been able to find it on the network then?

Running Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because something does not have a file share does not mean it does not have an IP.

The drobo software likely just uses its own software for communicating, you can run the command `netstat -b` from an administrative command prompt to see all connections programs on your computer are making. One of them will be the drobo software and you will be able to see what the IP is.

Comment: I can't find an entry for the Drobo on the list created from <netstat -b>, nor on DHCP list on the router
The Drobo software (Drobo Dashboard) has an autodetect feature - which so far has not been able to detect the Drobo.
Or a manual IP entry, which is why I'm trying to find the Drobos IP

Comment: So when you do `\doboshare` what opens? You said it worked eairlier, but now it the dashboard can't find it?

Comment: Opens up an explorer window and shows the two drives in the Drobo
[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14633641/PrntScrn.png)

Comment: just do `nslookup droboshare` from the command line. Also try `ping droboshare`

Comment: `nslookup droboshare` didn't work, but `ping droboshare` gave me a ip of 192.168.1.85 [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14633641/PrntScrn2.png), which I put into the DroboDashboard, but that status 'circle' has been going for over an hour [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14633641/PrntScrn3.png)

Comment: I just realised that if 'run' `\\192.168.1.85` it will show up in an explorer windows just like `\\droboshare` would.
However Drobo Dashboard still can't find it on that IP :O

Comment: I would say ask drobo's tech support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience Scott.
I got it working!! :)
It was a combination of Windows Firewall not working properly (had to run combofix to reset it) and had to downgrade the Drobo Dashboard software (the newer ones don't support the Droboshare).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Drobo's 2 ethernet ports bonded to one MAC/
IP, and a MAC filter on your internet, an update may cause the bonded connection to use the second MAC address that isn't on your allow table.  Temporarily remove MAC restrictions on your network and see if the Drobo pops up.